# Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{|x|}$ on $\mathbb{T}^{n}$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Let $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2} ~$  for $~x\in\mathbb{T}^n=[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]^n$, $~n\geq 2$.

We can define the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$ as

$$ \hat{f}(k)= \int_{\mathbb{T}^n}\frac{e^{2ik\cdot x}}{|x|} dx$$

for $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, since $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{T}^n)$ if $n\geq 2$.

My question: is $\hat{f}\in l^{p}(\mathbb{Z^n})$ for $p=1$, or other possible value of $p$ ?

By Haursdorff-Young's inequality, we can partially answer this question. But I want some refined estimates.

Another related function is $g(x)=\frac{1}{w(x)}$, where

$$ w(x)=\sqrt{\sin^{2}\left({x_1}\right)+\sin^{2}\left({x_2}\right)+\cdots+\sin^{2}\left({x_n}\right)}.$$

And I have the same question to $\hat{g}$.

In my point of view, the property of $\hat{g}$ is more important.

If we can obtain the sharp upper decay of $\hat{f}$ or $\hat{g}$, or we can prove that $\hat{g}\in l^1(\mathbb{Z^n})$, that will be excellent.

Comment: As an heuristic, look at the whole space, then the Fourier transform of $1/|x|$ is a multiple of $1/|x|^{d-1}$. Restricting this function on a box should keep the high frequencies, and so your Fourier transform should behave like $1/k^{d-1}$, and so should be in $l^p$ for $p> \frac{d}{d-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. By a similar argument (check the detail) of Example 2.4.9 in the book GTM249 , I can prove the claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is to show the following assertion. Any comments are welcome.

"The Fourier series of $g$ defined above has decay order of $\mathcal{O}(|k|^{-n+1})$ as $|k|\rightarrow \infty$, $n\geq 2$."

The idea is essentially from Example2.4.9 of the book GTM249.

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, denote by $|x-y|$ the general distance of $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. First notice that $g\in l^1(\mathbb{T}^{n})$. From the classical distribution theory (Thm2.4.6 of GTM249), we know

\begin{equation}\label{*}
\mathcal{F}({|x|^{z}})=C_{n,z}|x|^{-n-z}~~~~(*)
\end{equation}

for all $z$ with $-n<\Re z<0$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform of $|x|^{z}$ as a distribution, $C_{n,z}$ is a constant dependent on $n$ and $z$. Thus if $z=-1$ then the decay at infinity behaves like $|x|^{-n+1}$. Notice that $g(x)\sim |x|^{-1}$ near the origin, so a similar result is expected.

The first step is to make the integral to the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$, we use a decomposition

$$ \sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^n}\eta(x+\pi j)=1$$

holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\eta\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with appropriate support (not including other point in $\pi j$, $j\in\mathbb{N}^n\backslash\{0\}$), and equal to 1 near the origin. Then by the periodicity of $g$ and a translation, we get

$$ \hat{g}(k)=\sum_j \int_{\mathbb{T}^n}\frac{\eta(x+\pi j)}{w(x)}e^{2ik\cdot 
 x}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\eta(x)}{w(x)}e^{2ik\cdot x}dx.$$

Therefore, $\hat{g}(k)=\mathcal{F}{(\frac{\eta}{w})}(2k)$. The latter $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform in $\mathbb{R}^n$, here we can understand $k\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Next we write

$$
\mathcal{F}{\left(\frac{\eta}{w}\right)}=\mathcal{F}{\left(\left(\frac{\eta(\cdot)|\cdot|}{w(\cdot)}-1\right)\frac{1}{|\cdot|}\right)}+\mathcal{F}{\left(\frac{1}{|\cdot|}\right)}=:\mathcal{F}(g_1)+\mathcal{F}(g_2).
$$

Then using a smooth cut-off $\psi$ with $\psi=1$ near the origin, we get

$$
\mathcal{F}{\left(\frac{\eta}{w}\right)}=\mathcal{F}(g_1\psi)+\mathcal{F}(g_1(1-\psi))+\mathcal{F}(g_2)=:I_1+I_2+I_3.
$$

We shall see that
$$
I_{1}=\mathcal{O}(|k|^{-n}),~~I_{2}=\mathcal{O}(|k|^{-N}),~~I_{3}\sim |k|^{-n+1}
$$
as $|k|\rightarrow \infty$ for all large $N$ and our proof is complete (note that here $\mathcal{F}{\left(\frac{\eta}{w}\right)}$ coincide with the Fourier transform as a distribution).

For $I_{3}$, we use (*). Now we analysis $I_1$, by a direct computation and an induction (it is important) we get

$$
\varphi(x):=\frac{1}{|x|}g_1(x)\psi(x)
$$
has derivative estimate $\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x)=\mathcal{O}(|x|^{-|\alpha|})$ as $|x|\rightarrow 0$ for all multi-index $\alpha$.

Therefore,

$$
\partial^{\beta}(g_1(x)\psi(x))=\partial^{\beta}(|x|\varphi(x))=\mathcal{O}(|x|^{1-|\beta|})
$$

as $|x|\rightarrow 0$ for all $\beta\in\mathbb{N}^n$. So
$$\partial^{\beta}(g_1\psi)\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
for $|\beta|=n$ and we obtain the desired estimate for $I_1$ by the relationship between Fourier transform and the derivative.

As for $I_2$, a similar argument shows that

$$
\partial^{N}(g_1(x)(1-\psi(x)))\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$

for $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough. Thus we have finished.

Comment: I learned that in an article https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aa9008 , the author consider similar question in appendix B.

Comment: Great, warning however about your assertion $(*)$. This is not true for any $z\in\Bbb C$. For example, for $z=0$ one gets the Dirac delta, and more generally, if $z>0$ is not an even integer, then $1/|z|^{n+z}$ is not locally integrable (so not a distribution) and one obtains the principal value of $1/|z|^{n+z}$, which is a distribution that is an analogue of $1/|z|^{n+z}$. Your property $(*)$ is true without all these kind of problems if $z\in(-n,0)$.

Comment: Oh thanks! You are right. In GTM249 this distribution $u_z=|x|^z$
 was originally defined for $\Re z>−n$
 and then extended to whole $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Then $\hat{u_z}=u_{-n-z}$.

Comment: In the step $ \partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x)=\mathcal{O}(|x|^{-|\alpha|}~)$, I don't know how to explain it briefly. I directly compute the (Laurent??) series of φ and the problem actually reduce to prove $\partial^{\alpha}(x_1/|x|)=\mathcal{O}(|x|^{-|\alpha|}~)$.